# Reverse order when using std::cout

Tags: c++, cout

The program below outputs 10. I expected it to first print 0 (the else branch of function f) and then to print 1. How come that the order is reversed?

```
#include <iostream>     
using namespace std;

int f(bool& b){
    if (b==true){
        return 1;
    } else {
        b=true;
        return 0;
    }
}

int main () {
    bool b=false;
    cout<<unitbuf<<f(b)<<unitbuf<<f(b);

  return 0;
}
```

The output

```
10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of evaluation of arguments to a function is unspecified.  So, you have this argument on the left:

```
(cout << unitbuf << f(b) << unitbuf)
```

And this one on the right:

```
f(b)
```

Both being passed to `operator<<` (the last one).  Either one can be evaluated first.  If the one on the left is evaluated first, then the call to `f(b)` on the left will happen first, and return 0.  Then the one on the right will be called and return 1, resulting in an output of `01`.  If the one on the right is evaluated first, then *it* will return 0, and the one on the left will then be called, returning 1, resulting in the reversed output of `10`.

Comment: I think the reason is not really "the order of evaluation of arguments to a function", but rather "the order of evaluation of the operands in an expression". Because "cout << f(b) <<f(b)" is really "(cout.operator<<(f(b)).operator<<(f(b))" (I'm leaving out "unitbuf" here). In this expression the function call "f(b)" happens twice, and the order in which they are evaluated is unspecified.